# Set different style in one TextView as String programmatically?

Tags: android, string, textview, styles

I have this code below to display two String in one TextView.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              System.gc();
              TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext(), R.);
              String id = null;
              if (convertView == null) {
                    music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                    musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                    music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                    musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    id += musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);

                    tv.setText(id));
              } else
                    tv = (TextView) convertView;
              return tv;
        }
```

I want to set different style to two strings. First. Bold text style

```
music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                    musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
```

Second. Small text style

```
music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                    musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    id += musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Use Html tag for small and bold text and set Html text to using Html.fromHtml().

Comment: I have tried that and nothing happen. The answer below that I have accepted is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via `Spannable`:

```
music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
final String title = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);

music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
id += musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(id);
final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
sb.setSpan(bss, 0, title.length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(sb));
```

Then your first part will be Bold and the second will be normal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use those :

```
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

If you have 2 `String`, the easiest way that i can think is by creating 2 separate `TextView` and apply the above's code based on your need.

**UPDATE**

> How to return it if I create two separate TextView ?

Again, the easiest way that i can think is by creating a `List<String> ids`, and use it.

So, use :

```
ids.add(musiccursor.getString(music_column_index));
```

Instead of :

```
id += musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
```

Comment: How to return it if I create two separate TextView ?